# jQuery dialog frame drawing issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Using jQuery, I'm trying to open div with id elisabeth as a dialog withing rounded frame
as it is shown on the official website. It opens a window and even applies dark background, 
but doesn't show rounded corners and margins around the page. How can I make it work?

Here is my code:

```
<a href="#elisabeth" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop"><img id="elisabeth" src="images/elisabeth.jpg" width="80" height="100"/></a>
```

Comment: Please post some sample code which can be run to check the issue.

Comment: you are not clear enough but it could be a browser specific problem, ie doesn't shows rounded corners applied with css.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that jquery dialogs require that there be  data-role content and header divs for the styling to be applied appropriately. This will give you the full dialog with the close button in the header. If you only give a div with data-role="dialog" without the innards, then you will miss the styling.

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="dialog" >
<div data-role="header"><h3>Oops!</h3></div>
<div data-role="content">
    <p>You done screwed up, partner!</p>
</div>

</div>
```